# Does the weapon DPS contribute to Hailstorm?

Tags: torchlight-2

Does the Damage of the weapon contribute to e.g. Hailstorm and other Embermage skills such as Thunder Locus without mention of the DPS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spells that don't mention "% of Weapon DPS" don't depend on the damage of your weapon, as per description. Hailstorm's damage is dependent on the player level, as per description; levelling up the spell increases its mana cost and decreases its cooldown (as well as the milestone bonuses). Additionally, any gear that has the 'increase ice damage by x%' or the 'increase all damage by x%' enchantment also increases Hailstorm's damage.